# Is it possible to Short Jump on the 3DS?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

While playing Smash 4, I realized that I jump high when ever I want to jump (just by tapping the jump button, or moving the stick up for just a second).  Is it even possible to Short Jump on the 3DS version?

I never really thought about it before now, so I plan on doing some testing (to see if I myself can or can not Short Jump) when I get back to my 3DS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible - it's just difficult. You have to tap the button (or stick) as quickly as you possibly can.

Comment: It'll be much easier using the button. Just tap it like it's on fire!

Comment: I take it is much easier on the WiiU version?

Comment: It's really the same in both versions. It just depends on what controller you use and which button you assign it to, whether it's easy to tap or not.

Comment: Lol i sacrificed my hands to the devil in order to short hop with melee fox- this nothin

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

There is a video tutorial link [here.](http://youtu.be/HZYzad8zdLw?t=2m44s)